# Should I use a computed property here?

Tags: vue.js

I was listening to Adam Wathan's podcast and he and Chris Fritz (member of the Vue core team) were discussing computed properties and how a good way to think about when to use a method to perform a task or a computed property, is that if you are going to "return" a value, you should use a computed property.

Now I am a little confused as to whether I should be approaching this particular situation I have by using computed properties.

What I have below is an Employees List component in which I fetch a list of all employees in the database, and display them in a table, using bootstrap-vue. The curve ball is that the salaries are stored as integers, and I want to comma-format them when I display them. As you'll see, I added a dirty hack to do that and it is definitely not the right way to go about it. So I wanted to know what the ideal way to go about this might be?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>All Employees</h3>
        <b-table striped hover :items="formattedEmployees"></b-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                employees: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getEmployees() {
                axios.get('/api/employees')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.employees = response.data
                        this.employees.forEach(function (employee) {
                            employee.salary = '$ ' + employee.salary.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
                        })
                    })
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getEmployees()

            this.$root.$on('employee-added', data => {
                this.employees.push(data)
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Oh and at the bottom you can see that as this component is created, I am listening for a global event that gets fired when an employee is added via the Add Employee component. This is a bit broken - it adds the first new employee just fine, but when I start typing to add another employee, the first employee's name in the list changes as I type.

Thank you for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). It's implemented in JavaScript 1.5 (which was introduced in 1999) so it's basically supported across major browsers.

```js
var num = 34523459
console.log('$ ' + num.toLocaleString())
```